# How to manage errors within my Slim application?

Tags: php, rest, frameworks, slim

I'm not sure how I should be handling errors within Slim.

I am using a class with functions, e.g. login. When the user enters an incorrect password I'm unsure of how to give them to Slim so that they are able to be displayed to the user.

This is what I currently have:

Route:

```
$app->post('/submit', function () use ($app) {
    $post = (object) $app->request->post();

    if($app->user->login($post->log_mail, $post->log_pass)){
        $app->setCookie('mail', $post->log_mail, '2 minutes');
        $app->redirect('/inbox');
    }else{
         // redirect
        // display errors set by the $app->user->login() function.
    }
});
```

Class function:

```
public function login($username, $password){
    if(!empty($username)){
        if(!empty($password)){

            if($this->numrows($username, $password)){

                // login success
                return true;


            }else{die('credentials');}

        }else{die('password');}
    }else{die('username');}
}
```

How I make use of cookies:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(
[
    'debug' => true,
    'mode' => 'development',
    'cookies.encrypt' => true,
    'cookies.secret_key' => 'supersecret',
]);
$app->setCookie('something', 'something' '2 minutes');
```

Where I am currently using die(), I would like to set an actual error so that the Slim view is able to render it. I looked into Slim's Flash function but so far isn't working.

Comment: What version of Slim are you using?

Comment: Slim 2 I believe, I have noticed that there is now a third one but haven't updated yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

From the [documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/sessions/cookies/):

> If you use the session cookie middleware, you DO NOT need to start a
>   native PHP session.

Using `\Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie`, the code will be:

```
$app = new Slim();
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie(array(
    'expires' => '20 minutes',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
    'httponly' => false,
    'name' => 'slim_session',
    'secret' => 'CHANGE_ME',
    'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
    'cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
)));
```

This is my working solution, without using `\Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie`:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

// Twig
$twigView = new \Slim\Views\Twig();

$twigView->parserExtensions = array(
    new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension()
);

$app = new \Slim\Slim(
[
    'debug' => true,
    'mode' => 'development',
    'cookies.encrypt' => true,
    'cookies.secret_key' => 'supersecret',
    'view' => $twigView
]);
$app->setCookie('something', 'something', '2 minutes');

class User {

    private function numRows($username, $password){
        //Your magic here
        return true;
    }

    public function login($username, $password){
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        if(!empty($username)){
            if(!empty($password)){

                if($this->numrows($username, $password)){
                    // login success
                    return true;
                }else{
                    $app->flash('error', 'credentials');
                }

            } else{
                $app->flash('error', 'password');
            }
        } else{
            $app->flash('error', 'username');
        }
        return false;
    }
}

//Inject the new user
$app->user = new User();

$app->get('/', function () use ($app){
    $flash = $app->view()->getData('flash');
    $app->render('form.html');
})->name('Login');

$app->get('/inbox', function () use ($app){
    echo "Login OK";
})->name('Inbox');


$app->post('/submit', function () use ($app) {
    $post = (object) $app->request->post();
    if($app->user->login($post->log_mail, $post->log_pass)){
        $app->setCookie('mail', $post->log_mail, '2 minutes');
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor('Inbox'));
    }else{
        // redirect
        // display errors set by the $app->user->login() function.
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor('Login'));
    }
});

$app->run();
```

**form.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stackoverflow 33192640</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="./submit" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="log_mail">
        <input type="password" name="log_pass">
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    {% if flash.error %}
        Error: {{ flash.error }}
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Your problem should be [connected to the PHP session](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/54-app-flash-doesnt-work). You have to set it on top of your file:

```
session_start();
```

Comment: Nope, I am using Slim's cookie manager so I am not required to manually start a PHP session. The use of $app->flash doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: How are you using it? Please update your question with your Slim's cookie manager code.

Comment: Updated. See main question

Comment: Thank you, this is working I managed to figure out the cause. For some reason I think that flash errors are being stored in the native PHP session even though I am using the Slim cookies. Not sure if this is a bug or not but when i used session_start(); in combination with my original code it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I misread the question, i think what you are looking for is a simply try catch structure defined your custom exception like this.

```
class LoginException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }
}
```

With your code looking like this.

```
public function login($username, $password){
    if(!empty($username)){
        if(!empty($password)){

            if($this->numrows($username, $password)){

                // login success
                return true;


            }else{ throw new CustomException('Login error', 1);}

        }else{throw new CustomException('password error', 2);}
    }else{throw new CustomException('username error', 3);}
}

try {
 if($app->user->login($post->log_mail, $post->log_pass)){
        $app->setCookie('mail', $post->log_mail, '2 minutes');
        $app->redirect('/inbox');
    }
} catch (CustomException $e) {
    // Handle the different codes
}
```

Here you define an exception, which you give a message and a code, this will represent your different error situation. Know you can handle them differently in the code, and when they occour you just throw the exception with the code which is relevant.

---

What you are looking for is invoking custom errors, as described on http://docs.slimframework.com/errors/500/.

Raising a custom error would look something like this. Where you could invoke templates with custom errors and so on. There for no need for the if else logic in the submit section.

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e) use ($app) {
    DoSomethingElse();
    $app->render('mycustomerror.php');
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this display an application level error? I'm attempting to give the user a styled messaged saying something such as "Incorrect password", I have figured that $app->flash() works by var_dump() the entire array however I am currently having problems displaying a single flash error.

The reason I am using an if statement on the class function is to check whether it returns true or not, if(returns true){//do something}else{display error}

Comment: This is what I currently have tried:

$app->flash('error', 'incorrect!');

$flash = $app->view()->getData('flash');
print $flash['error']; // nothing(pretty sure this is reuturning NULL for some reason)

var_dump($flash); // this dumps all of the data, I also see the error message available within this.

Comment: I want to be able to set the error and then redirect them back to the original view page /index with that error data appended to it so that the index is able to render them a nice error message.

Currently on the index page I have used if is defined error{display it}, this works but I don't want to have to render the index to them while they are still on the post request aka /submit, I want to set the error then display it on the original page where the post input were.

Comment: Handle the exception and redirect accordingly to the error code, you are able to do with this code snippet as you intend 

Comment: But when I redirect how am I able to give the view access to the errors?

Comment: Pass the error code to the home page and check if there is an error code

Comment: That's the thing I have a section to check if an error code is present within my home page view but I'm unsure of how exactly to pass the error code to the home.

Comment: Look at stackoverflow or the documentation, http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/helpers/, there are many possibilities and a good ability to know how to look something up as that :)